# Specify Column Data Type When Using BindingSource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

How can I specify the datatype (`ValueType`) for a column when using `bindingsource`?

I would like to display a bound object's string property as `DataGridViewLinkColumn`.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the data you are binding. You can us set `DataPropertyName` property of column to the name of the property which you want yo display in the column

Comment: Currently the string property of the object is being displayed as text, but I want it to be displayed as a link, so I would like to set the column's `ValueType` to `DataGridViewLinkColumn` but I am not sure how to do that when the datasource is a `BindingSource`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.valuetype?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewColumn_ValueType

Comment: Thanks for the link @ChetanRanpariya but I am unable to apply those the `ValueType` to a column when using a `BindingSource`.

Comment: You can add a `DataGridViewLinkColumn` in code at run-time, bounding it to a specific field using its `DataPropertyName` property. Or pre-build the DGV's Columns in the Designer (always specifying the value of that property)

Comment: @Jimi Ah! Thanks! That was helpful as I was not aware that `AutoGenerateColumns` was a property that I could turned off.
I bound my object's properties that I needed and set their column's `ValueType`.
I relied on this example to do it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname?view=netframework-4.8
Thanks again!